# Asp.net Web API: HttpClient Download large files breaks

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have a web service (made in Asp.net Web API) that returns an xml file of about 10MB size.

The service has been tested with Fiddler and it is working

I am trying to download the file using HttpClient class. The problem is that the compilator never gets outside the `await client.GetAsync()` method, even if the API project returned the `HttpResponseMessage`.

This is my function

```
public async Task<XDocument> DownloadXmlAsync(string xmlFileName)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:51734/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));

        // When the copiler enters this next command, it doesn't get outside anymore
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/applications/ApplicationXml?fileName=" + xmlFileName);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        string stringResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(stringResponse);

        return xDoc;
    }
}
```

I updated also the maxRequestLength in web.config

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="15360" />
```

What i am doing wrong?

**Edit**

Calling the function

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
   var xmlTask = DownloadXmlAsync("1.xml");

   // doesn't reach here
   var result = xmlTask.Result;

   return View();
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `DownloadXmlAsync`?

Comment: I added the implementation in the question body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're causing a classic deadlock by calling `Result`. Instead, you should `await` the task:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
   var xmlTask = DownloadXmlAsync("1.xml");

   // doesn't reach here
   var result = await xmlTask;

   return View();
}
```

[I explain this deadlock in full on my blog,](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) but the general idea is like this:

- ASP.NET only allows one thread to be processing a request at a time.
- When you `await` a `Task`, the compiler will capture a "context" and use it to resume the method when the `Task` completes. In the case of ASP.NET, this "context" is a request context.
- So when `DownloadXmlAsync` (asynchronously) waits for `GetAsync` to complete, it returns an incomplete task to `Index`.
- `Index` synchronously blocks on that task. This means the request thread is blocked until that task completes.
- When the file is received, `GetAsync` completes. However, `DownloadXmlAsync` cannot continue because it's trying to resume that "context", and the "context" already has a thread in it: the one blocked on the task.
- Hence, deadlock.

Comment: Because i am a "classic":) Thank you, exactly my problem